# how to find smallest number in a list

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio, integer, difference

If I have a list of integers, how can I write a function that determines the smallest positive difference between numbers in a list? An example can be this:

```
[1; 3; 5; 6] // difference 1 (between 6 and 5)
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please try to solve it yourself, post your code, and explain where you got stuck, or with what particular aspect you need help. — That said, I found this problem interesting, and managed to solve it in about 3 lines of code using library functions. If you want a solution not using library functions, the code will be slightly longer.

Comment: If this was a C# question, I would agree with you, @dumetrulo, but with F# it's frequently about finding the right function in modules like List, Array, Option, Map, etc. Finding the right function is often not trivial, and so getting answers on SO is valuable even to experienced F# developers. After seven years with F#, I still haven't used half of these functions, largely due to lack of examples I guess.

Comment: @BentTranberg I agree with you on the library functions, it takes a while before you have a good idea which functions exist, and what they do. Now it's even harder because the documentation at Microsoft seems to be largely offline. — Question for dackfunk: do you want the difference between subsequent list items, or between any two list items? The latter will be slightly more complex (i.e. more than 3 lines of code).

Comment: @dumetrulo any two list items

Answer (score 1):

Following the discussion in the comments, I won't try to write a complete solution, but give you a hint about the functions that you need to get this to work.

If you are looking for the smallest difference between subsequent numbers, then you can use the `List.pairwise` function, which gives you a list of tuples with subsequent numbers. You can then pass that to `List.map` to turn the list of tuples into a list of differences (by subtracting one from the other) and to `List.min` to find the smallest one.

```
> [1;3;5;6] |> List.pairwise;;
val it : (int * int) list = [(1, 3); (3, 5); (5, 6)]
```

If you are looking for the smallest difference between any two numbers, then I would first sort the list using `List.sort` and then do the same thng as above - sorting the list will guarantee that the numbers you need to subtract to get the smallest difference will be next to each other.

Comment: tks a lot sir, 'problem' is that i need to iterate not only the subsequent numbers but all the numbers in that list. for example if i've [1,2,3] and i'm on the iteration of the number 2, i should compare it with 1 and 3.

Comment: Not really: if the list is sorted, you already know that the difference between the first and third elements cannot be smaller than between the first and second elements, so you don't need to do the comparison between the first and third elements anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Now I'll give you a complete solution, but one that is generic, so that it will work with any type that fulfill the [comparison and member constraints](http://[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/constraints), and it will also work on any collection type that implements [`IEnumerable<'T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1). That will shift your effort from figuring out which functions to use to what they are actually doing and how they are working together.

```
let inline smallestDiff source =
    source 
    |> Seq.sort
    |> Seq.pairwise
    |> Seq.groupBy (fun (x, y) -> y - x)
    |> Seq.minBy fst
// val inline smallestDiff :
//   source:seq< ^a> ->  ^b * seq< ^a *  ^a>
//     when  ^a : comparison and  ^a : (static member ( - ) :  ^a *  ^a ->  ^b) and
//           ^b : comparison

[1; 3; 5; 6] |> smallestDiff
// val it : int * seq<int * int> = (1, seq [(5, 6)])
```